2013 Honda Fit - I've accidentally deprogrammed ALL of my keys
2013 Honda Fit LX
I have two keys for a Honda Fit with a remote unlock/lock/panic fob. Inside there is a small board, a battery, and an immobilizer which prevents the car from starting if not programmed. They look like this: 
A couple of years ago, one fob stopped working, and did not work with a battery replacement. I left that be, because I didn't want to pay $300 for a new key from the dealer.
Recently, the battery for the spare was dying (range decreasing).
I had the idea to replace the battery on the spare, and at the same time get a blank replacement for the main key, swap the guts of it, and then program the guts to lock/unlock. This way I could avoid cutting a new key. In this model, the guts include the immobilizer - it is not in the key case. I read that you can reprogram honda fit keys using this process (turn key, hit lock, repeat)
Following this process, attempts to program the 'new' key failed, and in the process, I seem to have deprogrammed or unpaired my spare key! The key locked the door, indicating "vehicle is in remote programming mode", but the 'pair' step must have failed.
I am not sure if the system detected the knockoff key, or some other kind of blanket deprogram kicked in, or something else.
Now, the 'main' key doesn't work at all (because the immobilizer didn't program), and the spare works, but only as a physical key.
I've tried to repeat this process a few times to see if I could program the 'spare' (originally working key, with original parts), but this didn't work.  I've also tried removing the battery of the spare to see if it would reset - the only indication I have at the moment is that the 'spare' (original key) flashes then holds the led on for a few seconds after a press, whereas the 'knockoff' replacement key simply flashes red and does not stay on.
My questions are - how do I fix this? Can I at least reprogram the original key? Can I get them both working? What went wrong?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Can you add more details as to what happened during the procedure? Did the locks cycle when entering the programming mode? Did they cycle again when holding the appropriate button on the key fob? Or did both fobs go silent?

@RaphaelP will add more detail - the locks went into programming mode (they locked upon press), but the key didn't respond to a lock command (which is supposed to pair/set) after this.

See if you can find online a slightly different or more detailed procedure to follow. These programming procedures have some "tight" timings on the steps. As you deprogrammed your original fob, you probably were able to enter programming mode but didn't act the right way in the right time.

Googled your year, model and remote programming. Honda programming; https://www.hondapartsonline.net/blog/how-to-program-your-honda-remote. Youtube videos; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ox1O_hN2o24, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwTfV3sJ8os, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-clUhDCvmA, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mK7kTo8_nY8, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrVw7YUyLjU. If you have your Fit owner's manual or online from Honda, you may be able to have spare remote keys cut by stores capable of duplicating keys (Home Depot, Lowes, etc).  Some require the master key to duplicate spares.

@FDryer Yes, these are exactly the instructions followed above that got me into my current situation. I do not need a key cut, I need 1) an immobilizer to be programmed and 2) to somehow reset my factory key back to its settings.

Unfortunately, your options may be either a friend, acquaintance performing programming, calling a mobile locksmith or calling a local Honda dealer to fix this. Sometimes diy attempts at programming from seemingly easy instructions are not as easy as it appears.
